# Trouble in inflated listview

Tags: android, image, listview

I am working on customize (inflated) list view. In which I have used the text and background image for text (as per the condition). 
Now I am facing problem in scrolling the list view that background of text view is overlapping to the other text views.
Here is the sample code:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

 View icontextlayout=convertView;
     icontextlayout= inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_complex_list, null);
     TextView Txt1=(TextView)icontextlayout.findViewById(R.id.txt1);
if(disp1==true)
{
Txt1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pic)
}
    else
Txt1.setText("Text1 "+strUser);//

    TextView Txt2=(TextView)icontextlayout.findViewById(R.id.txt2);
if(disp2==true)
{
Txt2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pic);
}
    else Txt2.setText("Text2: "+strIndus);
return icontextlayout;
```

}

Could you please help me out that background image pic do not overlap the others background.

Thanking you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you must set a default background when you don't need a background. For instance:

```
if(disp1==true){
    Txt1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pic);
    Txt1.setText("");
}
else{
    Txt1.setText("Text1 "+strUser);//
    Txt1.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
}
```

Also, if you don't mind, I like to give you my opinion about your code:

- That's not they way in which list are usually populated. Take a look at this answer: [How to load the Listview "smoothly" in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320478/how-to-load-the-listview-smoothly-in-android/1321565#1321565)
- `convertView` is used to reuse rows. In your case you are doing something like:

---

```
View icontextlayout=convertView;
icontextlayout= inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_complex_list, null);
```

---

Which is bad, because you are not actually using the `convertView` (when you call `inflater.inflate`) it will create a new row, thus your list will be really slow.

- `if(disp2==true)` is redundant. You should consider using just: `if(disp2)`.

Comment: Really thanks for options too, I understand and the code was only to easily understand that which type of values are. Anyways you helped.