# Sliding from left to right to make call(like samsung contacts listview)

Tags: android, android-listview

I need to implement slide action event in my listview.

Call event should happen if i slide from left to right in every component of the lsitview. Below is my link for my code. kindly provide some suggestions.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class CityList extends Activity{
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://com.kumaran/TestSericve";      
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "getCityName";      
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://kumaran.com";      
    private static final String URL = "http://xxxxxxxxx.com?wsdl";
    ListView lv;
    ArrayList<String> cityName=new ArrayList<String>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.citylist);
        lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        SoapObject soapReq=new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);  
        SoapSerializationEnvelope soapenv= new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);           
        soapenv.setOutputSoapObject(soapReq);           
        HttpTransportSE ht=new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        try
        {
            ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapenv);        
            SoapObject result=(SoapObject)soapenv.bodyIn;           
            for(int i=0; i<result.getPropertyCount();i++){
                cityName.add(result.getProperty(i).toString()); 
            }
            lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(CityList.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,cityName));
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                        int i, long l) {
                    String cityName=lv.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
                    Pojo.setCityName(cityName);
                    Intent int1=new Intent(CityList.this,CustomerList.class);
                    startActivity(int1);
                }
            });
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Exception ", e.getMessage());
        }           
    }
}
```

Comment: what have you tried? Please avoid posting links to code, prefer posting the actual code. If its too big to fit nicely - It's probably too big period. Then try to narrow down the problem into a shorter example.

Comment: I tried an onItemClick already. I need to implement a slide/swipe action from left to right which should ivnoke the call option to call that respective number where i have clicked. Post will be big i used to put more codes. I cant and hesitate to scroll down again and again if i got a new answer. I hope pasting links is not against our forum rules. Right???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a suggestion as far as I can understand

You want listView like above..
Simply Inflate listview by inheriting it with ArrayAdapter Class and in on draw method call inflate

Use [xitij](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1367157/xitij) 
 answer for horizontal scroll view, and during scroll call intent, in intent pass the inflated view by using `putExtra()` method, either you can call implicit intent or explicit, its upto you.

For listview inflate check these stackoverflows' questions:

- [Android - Inflating ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084883/android-inflating-listview)
- [Trouble in inflated listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4921811/trouble-in-inflated-listview)
- [How can inflate a layout containing listview in a alert dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763506/how-can-inflate-a-layout-containing-listview-in-a-alert-dialog)

Check Lars Vogella's Link:

- [Adding a longclick listener to the list items (Lars Vogel)](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#miscellaneous_longclick)

Another link for inflating listView, close to your scenario but not exact:

- [A ListView with Checkboxes (Without Using ListActivity)](http://windrealm.org/tutorials/android/listview-with-checkboxes-without-listactivity.php)

Check these ones too for inflating listView:

- [List View Tutorial For Android](http://mfarhan133.wordpress.com/2010/10/14/list-view-tutorial-for-android/)
- [Customizing Android ListView Items with Custom ArrayAdapter](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429&q=customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter)
- [Android ListView with icons/images ….and “sharks with lasers”](http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-listview-with-iconsimages-and-sharks-with-lasers/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(
                new MyGestureDetector());
        View.OnTouchListener gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        };
        contactList.setOnTouchListener(gestureListener);
```

And make a inner class in your activity

```
class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

        private Button image;

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                float velocityY) {
int pos = contactList.pointToPosition((int) e1.getX(),
                    (int) e1.getY());

            if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > REL_SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH) {
                return false;
            }
            if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > REL_SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                    && Math.abs(velocityX) > REL_SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {

                int firstPosition = contactList.getFirstVisiblePosition()
                        - contactList.getHeaderViewsCount(); // This is the same
                                                                // as child #0
                int wantedChild = pos - firstPosition;

//Get the phone no from this position in your contact list and try this
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phone));
context.startActivity(intent);

}
```