# How to set a theme to a Listview populated with setListAdapter

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a listview which is simply populated this way:

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, aux))
```

'aux' it's `static String[] aux = null;`which is populated via Web Service.

I made a theme and tested with static listview elements, file lista.xml -> you can see it [here](http://pastebin.com/ge4cwg7v) (if you look in the bottom you will see I put "list item 1, list item 2", so I need to populate those values dinamically...)

My question is, how can I apply the theme to my listadapter?

I believe I start with :

setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this,
                R.layout.lista, aux))

But I have two problems.

(1) I dont know how to work with XML and populating from java (setlistadapter)
(2) I believe I will lose checkboxes.

However I appreciate if anyone can help in (1) first :) I really don't know what am doing now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.lista, aux))
```

is the start, you are right, but when you want a custom ListItem Layout you have to write a custom ListAdapter. You `extend ArrayAdapter<YourItemClass>` for example. There you override the method `getView()` and in this method you populate your custom Layout with your Values of your Aux Objects.

for an ArrayAdapter you have to set a id in your layout for your listview items

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/textview" android:layout_weight="1">

</TextView>
```

with id/textview you say your listAdapter to render into this View.

edit: oh and you have to learn and obey the holder concept of Lists. here: [How to load the Listview "smoothly" in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320478/how-to-load-the-listview-smoothly-in-android/1321565#1321565)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I have a problem... Based on your suggestion, I quickly replace the android:text for android:id (as you state), and had to replace the adapter for setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.lista, R.id.textview,aux));

The thing is: for every listview element is creating all other elements of the layout, so it's all messed up. How can I solve this?

Comment: Perhaps your underlying modeldata is a "all in one" object, so you have to define the getItem(int) method in your Customized ListAdapter. In this method you define how to get one item from your ItemObject(aux).