# ListView or recycle views myself?

Tags: android, listview, recycle

I have an app which loads a boatload of images and displays them in a `TableLayout` which is inside a `ScrollView`. At run time I get the width of the layout parent and use that to determine how many images can go in each `TableRow` (all of the images are of a set size).

I'm concerned about memory issues when loading more and more images. I know ListView recycles its views but I don't know how to dynamically change number of views in each item. I am only aware of inflating XML which isn't going to change the number of views per item at run time.

So my question is what is easier - figuring out how to recycle views in my table by myself, or making a list's items change based on screen size? Just a link to a tutorial on how to do whichever is easier is good enough an answer for me.

Comment: You can Add imageviews using java code instead of inflating it everytime. Use getView method accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use ListView with the ViewHolder approach (you can see it here: [How to load the Listview "smoothly" in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320478/how-to-load-the-listview-smoothly-in-android)).

The ListView, when scrolled, removes the views that are no more visible and gets the views that are about to become visible. This way, it's better than using a ScrollView and a TableLayout.

Comment: Thats the info I was looking for. Thank you.